# Showing two wavefunctions are proportional to one another

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, eigenvalue

I am struggling to answer the following question:

Let *ψ₁(x)* and *ψ₂(x)* be normalisable energy eigenfunctions for a particle of mass *m* in one dimension moving in a potential *V(x)*.  Suppose that *ψ₁* and *ψ₂* have the same energy eigenvalue *E*. By considering *ψ₁ψ₂' - ψ₂ψ₁'*, show that these wavefunctions must be proportional to one another.

I tried differentiating the Schrödinger equations and multiplying them together appropriately, but this just yielded a lot of messy algebra with no useful outcome.

I'm also wondering if there is a physical interpretation of this? Does it mean that the wavefunction for a normalisable energy eigenstate in one dimension always be chosen to be real?

Comment: $\psi_{1}'$ or $\psi_{2}'$ does not imply 'differentiating the Schrödinger equations', they are simply the first derivatives of these wave functions. Just try $\psi_{1}= a\psi_{2}$ with $a$ a constant. The wave functions are *degenerate*: they have the same energy eigenvalue.

Comment: [Degenerate solutions don’t exist in one dimension](http://www.physicspages.com/2012/08/23/degenerate-solutions-dont-exist-in-one-dimension/)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: thanks for that. The question seems incomplete, I think it should have read: $\psi_1 \psi_2'-\psi_1' \psi_2=C$.